# RxJava BehaviorSubject#onError(Throwable) equivalent in Kotlin Flow

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, kotlin-flow, rx-java3

I'm converting some RxJava code to Kotlin Flow in a project.

I came across a piece of code where `BehaviorSubject#onError(Throwable)` was being called.

I didn't find any way to do it with a `Flow` object.

```
// RxJava
val behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>()
behaviorSubject.onError(RuntimeException())

// Kotlin Flow
val mutableSharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
mutableSharedFlow.???
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: From the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/): "SharedFlow cannot be closed like BroadcastChannel and can never represent a failure. All errors and completion signals should be explicitly materialized if needed."

Comment: @akarnokd thank you very much for the reply. I became aware of that yesterday after some more research. The thing is that I wanted to use a different structure, which I shouldn't. Do you mind posting what you've just written so I can mark it as the correct answer? Thanks again ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/): "SharedFlow cannot be closed like BroadcastChannel and can never represent a failure. All errors and completion signals should be explicitly materialized if needed."

So you'd probably have to create a data class with slots for values and the exception, then use `takeWhile` to stop it.

(Sidenote: I happen to have a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/akarnokd/kotlin-flow-extensions#behaviorsubject) for kotlin flow that does offer an [error channel](https://github.com/akarnokd/kotlin-flow-extensions/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/hu/akarnokd/kotlin/flow/BehaviorSubjectTest.kt#L95-L124).)